# Random Value in php

Tags: php, arrays, random

I using the `rand` from php. That below script is working perfect, But My question is to give the priority for the one value in array(Show multi times). For example 100 times it randomly show the value, Is it possible to make the 0 to 99 times it echo the  `dofollow` and 1 time it show `nofollow` using `rand`

```
<?php
$input_nofollow = array("nofollow", "dofollow");
        $random = rand(0, 1);
        echo $input_nofollow[$random];
?>
```

Any Suggestion would be great.

Comment: Sorry what ? Do you want a simple for loop ?

Comment: if you have this much LOGIC, then this cant be a RANDOM one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$random = rand(0, 100);
$selected_key = 0;
if($random < 90) $selected_key = 1;
else $selected_key = 0;

echo $input_nofollow[$selected_key];
```

This give you a ~90% chance to get the index 1.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your awesome response only change i made is $random<=90 then only it returns dofollow

Comment: yeah, my mistake. I have changed the order.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a *shuffle*, not a random generator. Create an array with 99 "a"s and one "b", `shuffle` it, output in order.

Alternatively generate a random number between 1 and 100, loop with a counter, if the counter equals the random number output "b", else "a".

Answer (score 1):

Try Something Like This:

```
<?php
    $input_nofollow = array("nofollow", "dofollow");

    $random = rand(0, 100);
    $i = 0;
    while (1 /* Your Condition */ )
        if (++$i > 100) {
            $i = 0;
            $random = rand(0, 100);
        }

        if ($i == $random)
            echo $input_nofollow[0];
        else
            echo $input_nofollow[1];
    }
?>
```